# jQuery $.getJSON - How do I parse a flickr.photos.search REST API call?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, flickr

Trying to adapt the $.getJSON Flickr example:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
});
```

to read from the flickr.photos.search REST API method, but the JSON response is different for this call.

This is what I've done so far:

```
var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=YOURAPIKEYHERE&tags=yokota+air+base&safe_search=1&per_page=20";
var src;
$.getJSON(url + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.photos, function(i,item){
        src = "http://farm"+ item.photo.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.photo.server +"/"+ item.photo.id +"_"+ item.photo.secret +"_m.jpg";
        $("<img/>").attr("src", src).appendTo("#images");
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
});
```

I guess I'm not building the image src correctly. Couldn't find any documentation on how to build the image src, based on what the JSON response is. **How do you parse a flickr.photos.search REST API call?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it. For those that are interested, it's parsed like so:

```
var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=YOURAPIKEYHERE&tags=yokota+air+base&safe_search=1&per_page=20";
var src;
$.getJSON(url + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
        src = "http://farm"+ item.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.server +"/"+ item.id +"_"+ item.secret +"_m.jpg";
        $("<img/>").attr("src", src).appendTo("#images");
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
});
```

Notice the .photo was moved to the $.each method signature.

Comment: With this method, your API key is exposed. Do you have any concern/protection around this?

Comment: @yoshyosh: use https?

Answer (score 5):

This could be simplified by choosing the 'url_m' extras parameter and per_page parameter...

```
extras=url_m&per_page=4
```

Then all you need is this within the loop...

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", item.url_m).appendTo("#images");
```

Answer (score 3):

To access the Flickr API you must use `https: //`:

```
var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=YOURAPIKEYHERE&tags=yokota+air+base&safe_search=1&per_page=20";
var src;
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery API documentation for jQuery.getJSON() has a helpful example here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

The documentation provides a complete file as an example of how to parse the API call; it loads the four most recent pictures of Mount Rainier from the Flickr JSONP API. I'll reprint the file here as additional context that might be helpful, particularly for those new to using API's.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="images"></div>

<script>
(function() {
  var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
    tags: "mount rainier",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
        if ( i === 3 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for super answer, but I get a 20 item, what should I do to receive 50 photos?