# How to retrieve images from flickr with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have a page that allows users to enter search tags into input fields. What is required is the functionality to send the search terms to Flickr using Ajax/JS and then display the relevant images from Flickr on my page.

I am wondering are there any good video tutorials on this as I haven't done Ajax or XML before. I have watched a few tutorials so far on beginner Ajax in general but can't find anything relative to what I want to achieve.

Also, is there any advice you would give me on how to achieve this. The front end/getting the input and storing the values in an array is complete. Just looking to send the terms, retrieve the images and display them on my page,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this tutorial to understand AJAX and flickr API
http://kylerush.net/blog/tutorial-flickr-api-javascript-jquery-ajax-json-build-detailed-photo-wall/

See this answer to understand search api in flickr

[jQuery $.getJSON - How do I parse a flickr.photos.search REST API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513417/jquery-getjson-how-do-i-parse-a-flickr-photos-search-rest-api-call)